# Pandas: replacement with boolean values gives inconsistent results

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have a dataframe which consists of checkmarks like `x` and `v` which I am replacing with booleans with the following line:

```
df.replace({'v': True, 'x': False}, inplace=True)
```

Before running `df.replace()` the type of all columns according to `df.dtypes` is `object`. After `replace()` all the other columns are still `object` except a single column which is of type bool, and the values in it are of type `numpy.bool_`. Pycharm shows this specific column with red background for True values as can be seen below.

[image: pandas boolean dataframe]

Why this might be happening? Isn't `object` appropriate for storing booleans? And why is `pandas` changing the `dtype` from `object` to `bool` for this single column? What exactly controls it and how can I enforce keeping the dtype to `object`?

Would there be a reason to have all columns as `pandas.np.bool` instead, e.g. for performance reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas stores series internally as NumPy arrays. When a series has mixed types, Pandas / NumPy has to make a decision: it chooses a type which encompasses all types in that series. As a trivial example, if you have a series of integers with type `int` and change a single value to `float`, your series will become type `float`.

In this example, your 0th and 2nd series have `NaN` values. Now `NaN`, or `np.nan` is considered `float` (try `type(np.nan)`, this will return `float`), while `True` / `False` are considered Boolean. The only way NumPy can store these values is using dtype `object`, which is just a bunch of pointers (much like a list).

Your 1st column, on the other hand, only has Boolean values and can be stored with type `bool`. The benefit here is since you aren't using a collection of pointers NumPy can allocate a contiguous memory block for this array. This will yield performance benefits relative to an `object` series or `list`.

You can test all the above yourself. Here are some examples:

```
s1 = pd.Series([True, False])
print(s1.dtype)  # bool

s2 = pd.Series([True, False, np.nan])
print(s2.dtype)  # object

s3 = pd.Series([True, False, 0, 1])
print(s3.dtype)  # object
```

The final example is interesting because in Python `True == 1` and `False == 0` both return `True` because `bool` can be considered a subclass of `int`. Therefore, internally, Pandas / NumPy has made a decision to not enforce this equality and choose one or the other. The corollary of this is that you are advised to check the type of your series when dealing with mixed types.

Note also that Pandas performs checks on dtypes when you update values:

```
s1 = pd.Series([True, 5.4])
print(s1.dtype)  # object

s1.iloc[-1] = False
print(s1.dtype)  # bool
```

Comment: But in this case all the columns were initially parsed as `object`. The docs at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html do not mention that modifying cells automatically converts the `dtype`.

Comment: @ccpizza, You're right, it's not mentioned in the docs. But it's true (I've added an extra example to illustrate). I've also added some behaviour which may not be obvious, i.e. not equating `False == 0`.

Comment: So, if, for example, I want to have all columns to bool type is there a way to force it, while setting the invalid cells to `nan`?

Comment: @ccpizza, No, that's not possible. Because `np.nan` has type `float`. But `bool` only allows `True` & `False`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer @jpp